# How to give jenkins permission?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Trying to copy angular dist files from Jenkins workspace to nginx's directory via following command below.
`yes | cp -rf /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/angular/dist/codesandbox/ /var/www/html`

However this gives an error:

`cannot create directory '/var/www/html/codesandbox': Permission denied`

I gave root user permissions to folders above but still nothing changed. I had another doubt why is the copy command copying codesandbox folder to /var/www/html/ . Really not able to make heads or tails of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pretty much depends how you run Jenkins.

In general Jenkins executes the jobs on a special user, normally named `jenkins`. Try executing something like `whoami` in your pipeline and you will get the username of the user that's missing the permissions.